# transpose column to row php html mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have some data in a MYSQL database table that I need to "print" in a HTML web page, but I need that this information be shown dynamically in a 3 row and a maximum 12 column table.

Each column must show three sets of information, that will be displayed in each row, like the table below.

[image]

Is there a way to do this using PHP and/or HTML?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you show what your table looks like?

Comment: show us the raw data structure..